# preg_split url with a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have an string e.g.:

`src="http://www.domain.com/sub_folder/xyz_17215_andso_on_01-file_08.html"`

and want to split this at every character that is not a letter or number.

With

```
/[a-z0-9]/
```

I get an array with all the characters but what's the opposite of it to get all the words and numbers?

Comment: you may like  [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
$result_array = preg_split('/[^a-z0-9]+/', $string_to_split);
```

Comment: So simple... I tried this, too but with the ^ outside the []. I think I will never learn this regular expressions. Thank you. :)

Comment: @netS: You're welcome! Regarding `^`: `[^...]` means "any character other than `...`. But outside `[...]`, `^` means "start of string" (or sometimes "start of line").

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing new code to solve a problem, use the built-in functionality that PHP provides to you in the `parse_url()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php